# Load data from server in PickerView IOS Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am working on IOS application where I want to show the data from the server in my PickerView. I am very new to Ios Development thats why I am confused how to load any `ParseObject` data in my `PickerView`. My `ParseObject` contains "title" & "status" values. I want to show the value of "title" from ParseObject in my PickerView so later on if I am clicking on `PickerView` I can get that ParseObject also. My code is given below, Kindly guide me how to show ParseObject data in my PickerView.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {



    @IBOutlet weak var positionPickerOutlet: UIPickerView!
     var pickerData: [String] = [String]()
     var selectPositionsData: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.positionPickerOutlet.delegate = (self as UIPickerViewDelegate)
        self.positionPickerOutlet.dataSource = (self as UIPickerViewDataSource)
        getPositionData()
    }

    @IBAction func cancelFunction(_ sender: Any) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Sign Up Canceled")

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        // Row count: rows equals array length.
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    titleForRow row: Int,
                    forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        // Return a string from the array for this row.
        return pickerData[row]
    }
```

// Here I am calling a ParseQuery function and getting a list of ParseObject and putting it in my selectPositionsData Array.

```
    func getPositionData(){

              let parseQuery = PFQuery(className:"UserPosition")
                parseQuery.limit = 100
                parseQuery.order(byAscending: "createdAt")
                parseQuery.whereKey("status", equalTo: true)

        parseQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects :[PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
            if objects != nil {
                // do something with the array of object returned by the call
                for parseObject in objects! {
                    self.selectPositionsData.append(parseObject)
// Here I am putting parseObject "title" in my array.

self.pickerData.append(parseObject.value(forKey: "title") as! String)
                    }
                    print(self.selectPositionsData)
                    self.positionPickerOutlet.reloadAllComponents()
                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does you ViewController conform to UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate? My guess is it does not since you are trying to cast 'self' to UIPickerViewDataSource and Delegate. 
Asked in another way: Is your numberOfRowsInComponent even triggered?

Comment: @Teetz thanks for your reply. No ViewController is not extending UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate. Do I have to use these two also?

Comment: Edit your question and show us the whole ViewController (with declaration). I think your ViewController should conform to UIPickerViewDataSource. Then you don't need to cast self to UIPickerViewDataSource (the same for the delegate)

Comment: @Teetz sorry.. Just now I checked it.. I am using both of them. I am editing my question and putting my full ControllerView

Comment: The problem is that you parse your data into 'self.selectPositionsData' but the dataSource for your PickerView is pickerData (which is empty as far as i can see from your code)

Comment: I removed that block of code where I was putting ParseObjects in my pickerData. Give me 1 minute I am editing it again and will show you

Comment: @Teetz thanks for pointing it out to me. Now I am getting Strings in my Picker. Now I want one thing that if I click on any of the item in Picker I want to know which ParseObject I clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an object from selectPositionsData[] belongs to index/row and get its property value from ParseObject. No need to iterate the string from selectPositionsData[] to seperate array for titles.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    titleForRow row: Int,
                    forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        // Return a string from the array for this row.
        return  selectPositionsData[row].value(forKey: "title")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your pickerViewDidSelect method get the value like that :

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            let title = self.selectPositionsData[row].value(forKey: "title") as! String
            let status = self.selectPositionsData[row].value(forKey: "status") as! String

           let objectAtIndex = self.selectPositionsData[row]
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer here. This work is done now. Can you please guide me how can I get an object when I tapped on PickerView.